# Install optional updates using Cluster-Aware Updating

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, failovercluster, windows-cluster, cluster-aware-updating

The question is simple - how can I install updates listed as "optional" in Windows Update using the Cluster-Aware Updating feature in Windows Server Failover Cluster?

I installed all the important updates and now the plug-ins say there are no updates left, but if you use Windows Update you can clearly see there are some.

EDIT: I found out that I need to provide the parameter BrowseOnly with the value True (or 1). I tried it and the CAU Microsoft.WindowsUpdatePlugin returns error that the argument value is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `QueryString` plugin parameter set to `IsInstalled = 0 and IsHidden = 0`, specifically:

```
QueryString = IsInstalled = 0 and IsHidden = 0
```

in the CauPluginArguments field in the GUI.

Or, from PowerShell:

```
Invoke-CauRun -ClusterName CL01 -CauPluginName 'Microsoft.WindowsUpdatePlugin' -CauPluginArguments @{QueryString = "IsInstalled = 0 and IsHidden = 0"}
```

The syntax of the `QueryString` parameter is described in the Windows Update Agent API reference: [IUpdateSearcher::Search method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=vs.85).aspx).

EDIT:
For comparison, the default query string used by the Microsoft.WindowsUpdatePlugin CAU plugin is described [here (How CAU Plug-ins Work)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134213(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_QUERY) and looks like this: `IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and IsHidden=0 and IsAssigned=1`, which limits it to important updates only.